# How do I convert MySQL unsigned ints to Protocol Buffer uint32s in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, protocol-buffers, primitive

I'm working on converting a bunch of old tab-separated MySQL database dump files into Protocol Buffers and have run into a snag. The MySQL table includes a field of type `int(11) unsigned`, which I have mapped to protobuf `uint32` in the `.proto` file. When parsing the MySQL records and trying to convert them to a protobuf message, it's tempting to parse that field using `Integer.valueOf(String)` (or `Long.valueOf(String)` to avoid overflows). However, the [Protocol Buffers Language Guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) indicates [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar) that in Java, `uint32`s are represented using the `int` datatype, but with the first bit being reinterpreted as the highest-order bit rather than as the sign bit.

So before I go write my own `String`->`uint32`-flavored-`int` parser, I thought it was worth asking whether anyone else has already solved this particular problem. What's the correct way of converting a `String` representation of MySQL `int unsigned` to a Protocol Buffers `uint32` in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## String to int representing uint32

I'd try parsing as `long` and then converting to `int`:

```
int i = (int)Long.parseLong(str);
```

Using `long` for the conversion avoids a `NumberFormatException` due to an exceeded range. The subsequent [narrowing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) will drop the more significant half of the resulting bits, leaving you exactly with the representation required by the protocol buffer.

## String to long representing uint64

A similar conversion for `uint64` using `BigInteger` could probably be written as follows (untested code):

```
long l = (new BigInteger(str)).longValue();
```

This relies on an implicit truncation, just like in the above case. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#longValue%28%29) states:

> If this `BigInteger` is too big to fit in a long, only the low-order 64 bits are returned.

## Int representing uint to long

If you want to convert such an `int` which actually represents an `uint32` to a `long` with positive sign, you should make sure to clear the 32 most significant bits, as these will be filled with copies of the most significant bit of the `int` value, due to the sign-extending nature of the [widening conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

```
long uintValue = intValue & 0xffffffffL;
```

Comment: I had come to a similar conclusion, but you implement it more cleanly than I did. This suggests a similar question: how to parse `unsigned bigint` to protobuf `uint64` by way of Java?

Comment: Your solution also suggests that unconverting can be done simply by casting back from `int` to `long`, which is nice.

Comment: @JoshHansen, I updated my answer in response to both your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If the endianness is not a problem, then you can threat unsigned ints as byte arrays of fixed length.